# Real-time speech to text with the Microphone Audio Input in Node JS using IBM Watson SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am recording a microphone input audio stream in RAW PCM data with Naudiodon Node modulle, I am also using the Node SDK of IBM Watson to get the transcript but it just process the audio that is recorded till that moment, then it just finishes piping the data and closes the stream.

How can I keep it alive so it works in real time?

```
const portAudio = require('naudiodon');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const readline = require('readline');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const ai = new portAudio.AudioIO({
  inOptions: {
    channelCount: 2,
    sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat16Bit,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    deviceId: 2,
    closeOnError: false
  }
});

const ws = fs.createReadStream('audio.raw');

ai.pipe(ws);
ai.start();

console.log("\nPRESS 'c' to stop recording\n")

const s2t = () => {
    const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
        authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: <apikey> }),
        url: 'https://api.eu-gb.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/ed2f65f9-f572-46c6-aa0e-7863ae2a3a0d'
    });
    
    const rs = fs.createReadStream('audio.raw');

    const transcript = rs.pipe(speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket({ contentType: 'audio/l16; rate=44100', 'continuous': 'true', 'channels': 2 })).pipe(process.stdout);
}

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
               
process.stdin.on('keypress', async (_, key) => {
    if (key && key.name == 'c') {
        ai.quit();
        process.exit();
    }
});

s2t();
```

I have also tried to just pipe the Naudiodon stream directly to the Recognizer but then it overflows and the output remains empty.

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: How is this question related to websphere?

Comment: Sorry, It is not, I wiil change it.